# MP4 Video Files Not Playing In HTML5

Tags: php, html, video, html5-video, mp4

I'm building a website for a client and I'm nearly at the end when I hit a major problem with videos.  I'm going a gallery of videos which link to a `video.php` page in which all of the videos are in `MP4` format.  So I've recieved the disc with all files on and added them to the relevant folder, but only one of these videos works.

In `video.php` I have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["type"])){$type = $_GET["type"];}else{
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
};
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){$id = $_GET["id"];}else{
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
};
?>
```

And:

```
<video width="690" height="auto" controls>
    <source src="cms/videos/<?php echo $type; ?>/<?php echo $id; ?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here is my link code:

```
<div class="video">
    <h1>Short highlights clip</h1>
    <p>Details...</p>
    <a href="video.php?type=weddings&id=070512_richard_zena_short">Play Video</a> &raquo;&raquo; // This video plays
</div>
<div class="video">
    <h1>Ros and Neil's video </h1>
    <p>Details...</p>
    <a href="video.php?type=weddings&id=070630_duke_unwin">Play Video</a> &raquo;&raquo; // This video does not play
</div>
```

The files for both videos are located in the same folder.

Can anyone please tell me why this may be happening or advise on how to correct it?

Comment: what browsers did you test in? that does make a difference here. Its probably a browser issue related to the mimetype being sent or the video encoding. iOS is really picky on this...

Comment: they are not `encoded` correctly if one will play but the rest will not

Comment: Yeah @cmorrissey, I've just noticed that the one that plays was created back in May, where all the others are from last week, so it's an encoding error.  I'll have to revert back to using flash!

Comment: don't do that, try something like http://mirovideoconverter.com/ and convert them real quick

Comment: Thanks @cmorrissey, but to be honest I've spent so long on this project and been messed about so much that I don't feel that I should have to do that when the files have been given to me incorrectly - I have 20 videos and they're all over 1 hour in length, some are over 2.  I've reverted back to flash, but again, only the first video is working - Could there be another problem?